# Accent Colors not Changing Shell Theme and Certain Applications

Tags: gnome, 22.04, icons, themes, colors

Hello everyone I just upgraded to 22.04 LTS and I noticed that the accent color changer only applies to the application theme and icon theme, but not the ***GNOME UI Shell theme***. The corresponding shell themes exist, and they show up in GNOME Tweaks, but they don't get applied when you change the accent color from `gnome-control-center`. The settings app only changes the accent color for icons and application themes.

In addition, the light/dark mode doesn't seem to change

ALSO, the GNOME Tweaks app is missing the "Legacy applications" section, and *still* has the "applications" menu but it doesn't change ANY of the actual 'legacy applications,' it only changes applications that AREN'T legacy.

Clearly, there are some packages messed up from my upgrade that was crashed and I had to resume it in the TTY.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, it isn't a problem and therefore doesn't need fixing. The accent color changer isn't supposed to change the shell theme. For me, using graphical applications and using the shell are different kinds of work and I want a different UI for each; colors, shades, and contrast that work in one don't necessarily work in the other. It's an interesting idea, though, so you might submit a RFE with the Gnome developers.

Comment: @MDeBusk Oh, I thought it was a problem because the theme names for the shell themes were exactly the same as the application theme, as if they were both supposed to change for the accent colors. Also, are you talking about a different kind of "shell?" Becasue you said "using graphical applications and using the shell are different kinds of work and I want a different UI for each" but when you use GNOME you are always "using" both. Seems like you're talking about the terminal shell...correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you weren't referring to the terminal, I'm sorry. I thought that's what you meant.

Comment: @MDeBusk Oh, that's ok haha. Yeah I fixed my question to clarify a bit more.